# ValueError: Dataset Duncan was not found

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am running this tutorial with statsmodel

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/regression_plots.html

However, in this line,

```
prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "car", cache=True).data
```

i got the error:

```
ValueError: Dataset Duncan was not found.
```

Any idea how to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code to

`prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "carData", cache=True).data`

Package name has been changed from "car" to "carData" in the Rdataset.